# Flash messages - how to show them properly - RAILS/JS

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I would like to display flash massages for few secounds on my website (without any visual effects - just massage colored depending on flash (notice, success, errors) Currently i have something like this in app.html.haml:

```
= flash.now[:success]
= flash.now[:notice]
= flash.now[:errors]
```

I would like to replace it with dynamic js massage which disapears

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap up your messages like this in `application.html.erb`

```
<% flash.each do |type, message| %>
  <div id= "main_flash_msg">
    <%= message %>
  </div>
<% end
```

%>

Then you can fade away your messages in your `application.js`:

```
$(function(){
  // any operation you might want to perform
  $('#main_flash_msg').fadeOut(5000);
});
```

Hope it helps!